# Specializations of Schur functions at consecutive integers

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, schur-functions, polynomials

Given a partition λ = (λ<sub>1</sub>, λ<sub>2</sub>, ..., λ<sub>n</sub>) denote with s<sub>λ</sub> the associated Schur function.
There exists a nice product formula for the principal specializations:

s<sub>λ</sub>(1, q, q<sup>2</sup>, ..., q<sup>n-1</sup>) = Π<sub>i<j</sub> (q<sup>λ<sub>i</sub>+n-i</sup> - q<sup>λ<sub>j</sub>+n-j</sup>) / (q<sup>j-1</sup> - q<sup>i-1</sup>).

Is a similar evaluation known for specializations of the type s<sub>λ</sub>(1, 2, ..., n)?

Comment: Two quick observations: for lambda = (1, 1, ...), e_k(1, 2, ... n) is an unsigned Stirling number of the first kind, and for lambda = (k), h_k(1, 2, ... n) is a Stirling number of the second kind.  

Comment: It does seem to be the case that it's always a rational function in $n$.  Is this obvious?

Answer (score 6):

Let's take the strictest meaning of "similar evaluation", i.e., a product formula.  The by the remark, the answer is probably no, because for instance the Stirling number s(9,3) = 118124 = 2*2*29531.

A different meaning is whether there is some explicit combination of nested sums and products for a Schur evaluation at consecutive integers.  I don't know the answer to that.  Unlike for a straight product formula, it is difficult to look for such formulas or rule them out.

The loosest possible meaning is whether there is an efficient way to evaluate s<sub>λ</sub>(1, 2,...,n).  The answer to that is an easy yes, because you can use the Jacobi-Trudi determinant.