Monomial symmetric polynomials evaluation at roots of unity
The monomial symmetric polynomials are defined see Wikipedia.
For an arbitrary partition $\lambda$ with $n$ parts
I'm trying to find the following values:
$$m_{\lambda}(\omega_0,\dotsc,\omega_{n-1})$$
where
$\left\lbrace \omega_{0}=1,\omega_{1},\dotsc, \omega_{n-1} \right\rbrace $
is the set of $n$-th roots of unity.

Essentially a repeat of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67600.

Is there any particular paper for special cases ?

You can find small values using Sage or SF (Stembridge's Maple package) to compute the plethysm $h_\lambda[p_n]$.

Here is a simple demo in Mathematica

Here's another way to think about it, a bit different from the solution linked to above:   Note that at this specialization $e_1 = e_2 = \dots = e_{n-1} = 0$ and $e_n =  (-1)^{n-1}$. So if you expand $m_\lambda$ in the elementary symmetric polynomial basis, then every term vanishes under this specialization except for the $e_{n^k} = e_n^k$ ones.  So up to a sign you are just looking for the coefficient of $e_{n^k}$ in the elementary expansion.
